# How does `.into()` know which type to convert to if `From` is implemented for multiple types?

Tags: rust

How does the the `<From>` trait know which type to convert to in different contexts if it's implemented for more than one type?

For example, i have three types that have some mutual conversions implemented. On `Character` i implement `From` for both `Token` and `AminoAcid`. Yet, when i call `.into()` in the hashmap i don't have to specify which type is required by the map's type definition. How is the trait aware of the context?

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Coordinate{
    x:f64,    y:f64,    z:f64
}
#[derive(Debug)]
enum AminoAcid {
    VAL, GLN ,ARG,...
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Token {
    Coordinate(Coordinate),
    AminoAcid(AminoAcid),
    Character(Character)
}


impl From<Coordinate> for Token  {
    fn from(coord: Coordinate) -> Self {
        Self::Coordinate(coord)
    }
}
impl From<AminoAcid> for Token  {
    fn from(aa: AminoAcid) -> Self {
        Self::AminoAcid(aa)
    }
}
// ------------------------------------------------- <<<<
impl From<Character> for Token  {
    fn from(c: Character) -> Self {
       Self::Character(c)
    }
}
impl From<Character> for AminoAcid  {
    fn from(c: Character) -> Self {
        Self::ALA
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------- <<<<

lazy_static! {
    static ref HASHMAP: HashMap<&'static str, Token> = { // Here the value type is Token 
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("ALA", Character::Second.into());
        m
    };
    
  static ref HASHMAP: HashMap<&'static str, AminoAcid> = { // Here the value type is AminoAcid 
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("ALA", Character::Second.into());
        m
    };

}
```

Comment: I'm far for a Rust expert but I'm pretty sure this is because of type inference - the `.into()` calls here must return the types they do because otherwise the `insert` calls won't be well-typed, given the types in the HashMap that you've explicitly specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Rust can deduce/infer types.
For example

```rust
fn f1(arg: u8) {
    println!("u8 in f1: {}", arg)
}

fn f2(arg: i64) {
    println!("i64 in f2: {}", arg)
}

fn main() {
    let a = 12;
    let b = 23;
    f1(a);
    f2(b);
    // f1(b); // expected `u8`, found `i64`
    // f2(a); // expected `i64`, found `u8`
}
```

`a` and `b` are declared the same way; at this point, the compiler just knows they are some kind of integer.
At the first call of `f1()`, since the expected argument is an `u8`, Rust deduces that `a` is actually an `u8`.
The same goes for `b` deduced as an `i64` at the first usage of `f2()`.
Of course, if after that we try to make the compiler deduce other types for these variables, it fails.

In your case, you declare your static bindings as hashmaps of a specific type: `Token` in one case, `AminoAcid` in the other.
Then, the brace used to initialise such a binding have to match this type; the type of the resulting expression (`m`) is deduced accordingly.
The way we initialise `m` expects the correct value type.
Consequently, the version of `into()` providing this type is chosen.

Comment: It absolutely is type inference. I should also add that it won't always be able to if the surrounding code hasn't given the type inference engine enough information, in which case you'd see a compiler error asking you to be more specific (either via adding more type hints or fully-qualified function syntax which specifies which `Into` trait you want to use)

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined the type of `HASHMAP`, the compiler infers which type is needed, since if it converted into the other type it would not compile. https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/inference.html